# Statistical test for player strategies results (win/loss/draw)

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval

What is the suitable statistical test for checking statistics significance and confident intervals for this type of data?

I have several agents (strategies) to play a game, and the result of each ***game end*** is recorded (see the attached image as a small sample of my data. I have thousands of such results).

At the end I'm counting the times each agent (***Black=First Player***) won, loss or did a draw against all the others.

For example strategy X (as Black player) has:

- 50% wins(4/8)
- 25% Losses (2/8)
- 25% Draws (2/8)

**My null hypothesis will usually be that the agents have equal strength and will therefore win an equal number of games. 
I want to use a statistical test to test if either player is better.**

[image: Data Sample]

Comment: I think people would need more detail to be able to help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each pair of strategies (x,y) you can easily test your hypothesis using CLT for proportions (see for example [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/inferential-statistics-intro/lecture/oJxbr/sampling-variability-and-clt-for-proportions)). Your null hypothesis would be "no strategy is better" or p = 0.5, and your alternative hypothesis may be p is smaller  / larger / different than 0.5.

Since you have *n* strategies, we need to better define what a 'better strategy' is. If you carefully select a sample of k*n*(n-1) games, where there are *k* games for each pair of strategies, then define *n* subgroups, where subgroup *s* contains all the k*(n-1) games of strategy *s*, a null hypothesis "strategy *s* is not better that average" would again translate to p(s) = 0.5 for subgroup *s*. If your alternative hypothesis is "strategy *s* is worse / better / different than average" - you may repeat the same test as before.

As for draws, I would count them as half-win half-loss - to keep p(s) = 0.5.

If the null hypothesis is "strategy *s* is not better than all others" and your alternative hypothesis is "strategy *s* in better than all others", you may use the method suggested by Dan Nettleton in *"Testing for the Supremacy of a
Multinomial Cell Probability"* (available [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/citations;jsessionid=F55E51459020AB24CCB3F0B568A10841?doi=10.1.1.143.1312)) or the method suggested by
Alessio Farcomeni in *"Testing Supremacy or Inferiority of Multinomial Cell Probabilities with Application to Biting Preferences of Loggerhead Marine Turtles"* (available [here](http://www.afarcome.altervista.org/supremacy.pdf)).